# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter add a hasChild() method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Here's my database:

```
Database:{
  X:{
     JK-KDUKSIDKSIIJDSL1:{
        text:"hello",
        name:"Donald J. Drunk"
     }
     JK-KDadDFDDIJDSL1:{
        name:"Killery Hlinton"
     }
  }
}
```

And I want to filter my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` such that only add to my `RecyclerView` data that contains the key `text`. How is this possible? How can I add it? Current code:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign, CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class, R.layout.recyclerview_template, CampaignHolder.class, ref) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(final CampaignHolder viewHolder, final Campaign campaign, final int position) {
            findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            MainActivity.this.holder = viewHolder;
            viewHolder.setTitle(campaign.title);
            //... Other "set" methods
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems difficult to implement Heterogenous typed Adapter. AFAIK,, `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is currently designed to work with same type of objects.

Comment: So, it's not easily implementable? Wow, I can't believe Firebase misses simple things like this. This is why I miss Parse

Comment: I have worked several times on both of these SDKs, but Firebase won for me. BTW, Firebase didn't know some geniuses still implement Hetrogeneous structures.

Comment: So it isn't normal for someone to want to filter data on a list? That's the dumbest thing I've ever heard.

Comment: Problem is with the structure of data you have and not filtering it. Refer this to learn how to structure your data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Comment: @ChintanSoni I am well aware of how to structure my data. Just having to create a node for what I want to filter is just absurd. That's why I'd rather filter.

Comment: And are you telling me that the tens of requests for filtering data shouldn't be there? Even when a Firebase Engineer approved of it?

Comment: Is your structure correct ? because your second object in X is missing `text` attribute

Comment: @That's the point, I want to filter such that if there's no `text` attribute, don't show the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the `onBindViewHolder` method in your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Something like this:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign, CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class, R.layout.recyclerview_template, CampaignHolder.class, ref) {

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(CampaignHolder viewHolder, int position) {
                Campaign model = getItem(position);
                if(model.getText() != null){
                    populateViewHolder(viewHolder, model, position);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(final CampaignHolder viewHolder, final Campaign campaign, final int position) {
                findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                MainActivity.this.holder = viewHolder;
                viewHolder.setTitle(campaign.title);
                //... Other "set" methods
            }
    };
```

With this approach you would still pull all data at the query location but entries without a text attribute just wouldn't be displayed. If that is unsatisfactory and you want to minimize the amount of data you download per query then the only other option I see is closer to what is mentioned in the comments above - meaning you would need to create a separate location that only stores those entries which have a text value.